# Execute a function when a time is equal to a certain value in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I am building an online e-commerce store, and I am trying to use rails with action cable to update a product from being out of stock to in-stock at a certain date time e.g `12:00:00 2020-02-19`.

The idea is as soon as the time is reached, I want to push a Websocket that the product is now available.

I have tried a few solutions such as:

```rb
  Thread.new do
    while true do
      if **SOMETIME** == Time.now
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "product_channel",content: "product-in-stock"
      end
    end
  end
```

The main issue with this approach is that it creates another thread and makes rails unresponsive. Furthermore, if this value is set for say 1 week from now I do not want every user who queries the endpoint to create a brand-new thread running like this.

Comment: Would be it an option to create a Rails task and create a cron job that calls your task? I.e. `bundle exec rails my_notification_task`

Comment: @hernanvicente Thank you for the suggestion, the issue is that each product has a different release time that I would like to set dynamically.

Comment: Rail tasks documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks

Comment: I suggest using Sidekiq. It allows to dynamically set time when a job will be executed.  `MyWorker.perform_at(**SOMETIME**)` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: I'm curious as to why the notification is time based and not based upon when the database gets updated with more stock?

Comment: @lurker The store requires the product to be release exactly on a specific time as this product is in high demand and many people are trying for it. Updating stock requires manual interaction which we are trying to limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option use sidekiq jobs or use whenever job gem
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs
Whenever allow you to set specific day and time, check the documentation for more info
https://github.com/javan/whenever